# On a host with two android phones connected, not able to run adb commands simultaneously on both phones from script in threads

Tags: android, parallel-processing, adb, execution

I have host machine connected two phones over USB. From script, I have given two adb commands separately from two threads respectively. I get connection reset error from adb in the log. Can we run adb commands in parallel ? Does it support ?

Comment: could you please share the exact error message you got? thanks

Comment: error: Connection reset by peer ( Couldn't read status )